# Filtering Sharepoint list data with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest, filter, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to development. I'm struggling with filtering the data related to specific field values in sharepoint list.
   I'm using AngularJs and REST to get all the items from SharePoint list. I need to filter data based on Region, Country and sites in that country.

Any help is much appreciated.

I'm storing all items in one variable as

```
$scope.items= data.data.d.results;
```

In the data below, Region, Country, Sites and contact are the SharePoint list field names, My data looks something like this:

```
    [
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite1",   "contact": "person1" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Spain",     "Sites": "Spainsite",     "contact": "person2" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite2",   "contact": "person3" },
  { "Region": "NA",  "Country": "USA",       "Sites": "USsite",        "contact": "person4" },
  { "Region": "SA",  "Country": "Mexico",    "Sites": "Mexsite",       "contact": "person5" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Hungary",   "Sites": "Hunsite",       "contact": "person6" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "China",     "Sites": "Csite",         "contact": "person7" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "Singapore", "Sites": "Singaporesite", "contact": "person8" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "India",     "Sites": "indiasite",     "contact": "person9" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Italy",     "Sites": "ItSite",        "contact": "person10"} 
]
```

I tried doing this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {Country:'Singapore'}">{{item.Country}}</div>
```

But if I use filter in this then if a new country is added to the list then it won't be filtered. Any help?

Comment: You need to give us some code, at least the data you have and what you tried so far, in order to be helped.

Comment: Do you understand it now? Sorry for my poor explanation, I'm very new to development. I am using ng-repeat to iterate through all the data and using filter such like: ng-repeat="item in items| filter: 'EU' " @theAlexandrian

Comment: But i also need to filter using country and sites, so if I use such filters then it won't be dynamic, if they update or add a new entry to sharePoint list then I will have to add a new entry to the code with another filter for that country.

Comment: I do not know about angularjs nor rest, just plain JavaScript. But I think you should do the task using a script instead of writing directly in the tag if you want it to be dynamic

Comment: @theAlexandrian can you write such filter in javaScript please?

Comment: Are you building a table? What is the result you are expecting? I have no clue

Comment: Yes sort of, first column will have Countries, second column contains the sites related to the specific country in that row and there will be a separate field that will show the contact for a site when we click on the site. @theAlexandrian

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow what you described in comments. This is what I came up with:

**PLAIN JS**

```js
var data = [
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite1",   "contact": "person1" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Spain",     "Sites": "Spainsite",     "contact": "person2" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite2",   "contact": "person3" },
  { "Region": "NA",  "Country": "USA",       "Sites": "USsite",        "contact": "person4" },
  { "Region": "SA",  "Country": "Mexico",    "Sites": "Mexsite",       "contact": "person5" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Hungary",   "Sites": "Hunsite",       "contact": "person6" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "China",     "Sites": "Csite",         "contact": "person7" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "Singapore", "Sites": "Singaporesite", "contact": "person8" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "India",     "Sites": "indiasite",     "contact": "person9" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Italy",     "Sites": "ItSite",        "contact": "person10"} 
];

var output = document.getElementById("table-output"),
  infoField = document.getElementById("info-field"),
  keys = { headers: [ "Country", "Sites" ], info: "contact" };
  
output.appendChild(buildTable(data, keys));

function buildTable(data, keys) {
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var header = document.createElement("thead");
  
  keys.headers.forEach(title => header.appendChild(drawCell("th", title)));
  table.appendChild(header);
  
  data.forEach(item => {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    keys.headers.forEach(title => row.appendChild(drawCell("td", item[title])));
    
    row.addEventListener("click", () => {
      infoField.textContent = ' ' + item[keys.info];
    });
    table.appendChild(row);
  });
  
  function drawCell(tag, text) {
    var cell = document.createElement(tag);
    cell.textContent = text;
    return cell;
  }
  
  return table;
}
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}

td {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div style="padding: .5em">
  Contact : 
  <span id="info-field"></span>
</div>
<div id="table-output" style="font-family: cursive"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @theAlexandrian, I want the same thing but in Angularjs, I don't know how to achieve the same with ng-repeat. And one country may have more than one site, I don't want a country to be repeated instead if a country is repeated with another site, I want the country to be shown only once and all the sites appear next to it in different rows. For example, here we have Germany two times, what I want is Germany: Germansite1 and Germansite2 below germansite1.

Answer (score 0):

What about making custom **filter** and assigning wanted filter values to:
each of **dynamicRegion, dynamicCountry, dynamicSites, dynamiccontact** variables.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.items=  [
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite1",   "contact": "person1" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Spain",     "Sites": "Spainsite",     "contact": "person2" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Germany",   "Sites": "Germansite2",   "contact": "person3" },
  { "Region": "NA",  "Country": "USA",       "Sites": "USsite",        "contact": "person4" },
  { "Region": "SA",  "Country": "Mexico",    "Sites": "Mexsite",       "contact": "person5" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Hungary",   "Sites": "Hunsite",       "contact": "person6" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "China",     "Sites": "Csite",         "contact": "person7" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "Singapore", "Sites": "Singaporesite", "contact": "person8" },
  { "Region": "AP",  "Country": "India",     "Sites": "indiasite",     "contact": "person9" },
  { "Region": "EU",  "Country": "Italy",     "Sites": "ItSite",        "contact": "person10"} 
]
  var dynamicRegion = "EU";
  var dynamicCountry = "Germany";
  var dynamicSites = "";
  var dynamiccontact = "";
  $scope.myFilter = function(item){
    if((!dynamicRegion || dynamicRegion == item.Region) && (!dynamicCountry || dynamicCountry == item.Country) && (!dynamicSites || dynamicSites == item.Sites) && (!dynamiccontact || dynamiccontact == item.contact)) return true;
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
 <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: myFilter">{{item.Country}}</div>
    
</div>
```